# How do I make the Expander Header change along with the List item as typing in field occurs?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, expander

How do I make the Expander Header change along with the ListBox item as typing in field occurs?

*** I just attempted to post this with an image, but this site does not allow me to post an image until I have a reputation greater than 10.  The image is simply a window capture of the running WPF program (source below) where the [New] button was clicked once, "John Henry Doe" entered into the Name field and "123-4567" entered into the Phone field, then in bold red "1) As I type here" with arrows pointing to the Name and Phone fields, then in bold red "2) This changes" with arrow pointing to the "John Henry Doe: 123-4567" item in the ListBox, then in bold red "3) But this does not change" with an arrow pointing to "New Contact" of the Expander's Header. ***

As can (if I was allowed to post the image) be seen in the image above, as the user types into the Name or Phone field, the ListBox Item changes.  It changes because I do a .Refresh() on the KeyUp event.  However, the Header of the Expander should be changing at the same time.  There is no .Refresh() for that as far as I know.  I want the Expander's Header to update as the ListBox's Item does, that is, while the user is typing.

The ListBox's DataContext is an observable collection of the class Contact.  The Contact class has a property called ListString with a get that returns the result of the method ListItem().  The ListBox's ItemTemplate simply binds to the ListString property.  The Expander's Header is bound to ListBox's SelectedItem.ListString and currently is only updated when selecting different ListBox items.  I need it to update as typing occurs.

Below is the XAML and C# code behind code.  The controls to the right of the ListBox are invisible until an entry is selected in the ListBox.  The [New] button inserts a new item into the ListBox and selects it, thereby casing the controls to the right to appear and focus given to the Name field.  As you type into the Name field and/or the Phone field, the corresponding item in the ListBox will update, but not the Expander's Header.  That does not update until you select another item in the ListBox.  I want it to update at the same time the ListBox item updates.  How do I do that?

```
<Window x:Class="Binding_List_Expander_04.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Binding List Expander 04"
        Height="350"
        Width="530">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                <ListBox Name="ContactList"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                         Width="166"
                         Height="270"
                         Margin="0,0,0,3">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListString}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Name="NewItem" 
                        Content="New"
                        Click="Event_NewContact_Click"
                        Height="23" 
                        Width="75" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ContactList, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <ScrollViewer Height="302">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Expander Name="ContactExpander">
                            <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ContactList, Path=SelectedItem.ListString}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="21,0,0,0"
                                        Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid Margin="3"
                                      TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Event_ContactName_TextChanged">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Text="Name:" />
                                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                                             Grid.Column="2"
                                             Name="ContactName"
                                             Text="{Binding ElementName=ContactList, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Text="Phone:" />
                                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2"
                                             Grid.Column="2"
                                             Name="ContactPhone"
                                             Text="{Binding ElementName=ContactList, Path=SelectedItem.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Expander Header="&#13;This is a place holder, there will be&#13;many Expanders following this one."
                                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Data and&#13;Information" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Expander Header="This is another place holder."
                                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Data and&#13;Information" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Expander Header="This is another place holder."
                                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Data and&#13;Information" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Binding_List_Expander_04
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContactList.DataContext = Contacts;
        }

        private void Event_NewContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contacts.Insert(0, new Contact());
            ContactList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            if (ContactExpander.IsExpanded)
                SetFocus(ContactName);
            else
            {
                ContactExpander.IsExpanded = true;
                SetFocus(ContactName);
            }
        }

        public void SetFocus(UIElement control)
        {
            control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (ThreadStart)delegate { control.Focus(); });
        }

        private void Event_ContactName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tb = e.Source as TextBox;
            Contact C = ContactList.SelectedItem as Contact;
            if (tb == ContactName)
                C.Name = tb.Text;
            else if (tb == ContactPhone)
                C.Phone = tb.Text;
            ContactList.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string ListString { get { return ListItem(); } } // See comments in ListItem() below.

        public Contact()
        {
            Name = string.Empty;
            Phone = string.Empty;
        }

        private string ListItem()
        {/*
          * This is a simplified version, the actual version is complicated and cannot be templatized.
          * Please, do not suggest templitazing this.  I know this simple version can be templitazed,
          * but the actual version cannot be templatized.  I need to know how to make this work as it
          * currently is.
          */
            if ((Name + Phone).Trim().Length == 0)
                return "<New Contact>";
            else
            {
                string li = Name.Trim();
                if (li.Length != 0 && Phone.Trim().Length != 0) li += ": ";
                return li + Phone.Trim();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for you help.